Could not Localize strings in my xcframework
I have a SwiftUI framework that's i want to implement Localizable Strings for English and Brazilian Portuguese, here is my project, code and github repo:
My HomeLocalizable.swift:
enum HomeLocalizable {
    // MARK: - Home -
    enum Home {
        static let title = HomeLocalizable.tr("Localizable", "home.title", fallback: "Financial Control")
    }
}

// MARK: - Implementation Details -

extension HomeLocalizable {
  private static func tr(_ table: String, _ key: String, _ args: CVarArg..., fallback value: String = "") -> String {
    let format = BundleToken.bundle.localizedString(forKey: key, value: value, table: table)
    return String(format: format, locale: Locale.current, arguments: args)
  }
}

private final class BundleToken {
  static let bundle: Bundle = {
    #if SWIFT_PACKAGE
    return Bundle.module
    #else
    return Bundle(for: BundleToken.self)
    #endif
  }()
}

String files:
String file 1
String file 2
Github project: https://github.com/TiagoLinharess/app-ios-financial-control-v2
I tried using Localizable in Text() view, the example above, and i couldn't get the translated value, only the keys or fallback

Is the Xcode project file that's generated by your XcodeGen config containing both of your languages? I don't know how XcodeGen handles this. To check, open the Project navigator and selecting the project (not the target), then the Info tab; you should see see 2 localizations. If you don't, then that's the cause of your problem.
